# Windows Mobile 5.0 Datagrid Column Size

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-mobile

So I built a small program for warehouse workers for a company that use this PDA device.
http://www.thebarcodewarehouse.co.uk/Images/Product/Default/large/Honeywell-Dolphin60s-image1.jpg

It has windows mobile operating system 5.0 [image]
As shown in the picture, the description and code column have the same size. I know it's an old technology but my manager insists to make the description column wider on the load( Manually we can make it bigger after it loads).

I have written this code.

```
    DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
    DataGridTextBoxColumn cs = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();

    cs = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
    cs.MappingName = "Desc";
    cs.HeaderText = "description";

    cs.Width = 150;
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(cs);

    cs = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
    cs.MappingName = "Code";
    cs.HeaderText = "code";
    cs.Width = 50;
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(cs);


    cs = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
    cs.MappingName = "barcode";
    cs.HeaderText = "barcode";
    cs.Width = 90;
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(cs);

    DgView.TableStyles.Clear();  //DgView is the Datagrid
    DgView.TableStyles.Add(ts);

            DgView.DataSource = AllKinds.AsEnumerable().
              OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Desc")).
              Select(p => new
              {
                  Description = p.Field<string>("Desc").Trim(),
                  Code = p.Field<string>("Code").Trim()
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Try setting the DgView style after setting the DgView.DataSource. Double check the DgView content against your mappings. BTW: the screen shot shows a device running Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 and NOT Windows Mobile 5!

Comment: Oh sorry in my project it was put windows mobile 5. I tried what you said but still when it loads, the columns are all the same sizes.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the assignment. Look at the column headers, even they are not applied. Your header in style says "code" and "description" but the headers shown are "Code" and "Description".

Comment: Yes, I know. The header text is getting the names of the select properties. I put the mapping names the same as in the select, it is still not mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the TableStyle Mapping name, the name of the table that the style is to be assigned:

```
    DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
    //which table is to style
    ts.MappingName = "data[]";
```

In the above code I used a array of a data object. I do not know what to use for your construction. See [also](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle.mappingname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at MSDN.

On another strange (colorfull, lots of images) [site](http://movies4u.ir/?t=1202&e=128217730&ref=selfmovies4u) one says:
"I can use BindingSource.GetListName(null) to get the string representation of the anonymous type."
and
"tableStyle.MappingName = dgCustom.DataSource.GetType().Name;"

A datagrid can have several datasources, normally datatables. Each TableStyle define the Style for a table and in there the Style of the columns. The TableStyle.Mapping prop defines the style<->table relation.

Comment: I tried some of the things you mentioned it still did not work. My List is called "Allkinds" , and the Datagrid is called "DgView", can you show me a code. The header text is getting the property names of the select statement. It is like I am doing all the styles for nothing.

Comment: ts.MappingName = DgView.DataSource.GetType().Name; after the data fill should work. Otherwise you need to provide your AllKinds data to the post.